# Finding numbers of man sections

Tags: macos, manpage

I'd to see a table of `man` sections like at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections inside `man`.

I tried `man man` but didn't see anything. Is this any easy way to find this information?

Am running OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the manual page of **[manpages(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/manpages)**. The 4th section is MANUAL PAGE SECTIONS where you can find the major manual page sections.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any help?

[Apple Developer Manpages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/#)

By the way, here is a really handy tip if you work in the Terminal on a Mac. If you put your mouse over a command, eg. the word `pbcopy` in `Terminal`, and right click your mouse, you can open a manpage in a lovely, shiny, new, yellow window all of its own which you can scroll up and down and refer to while you are coding/scripting... see image.

[image]